# warnings silenced by multiline assert condition in g++ when source code is first preprocessed and then compiled

Tags: c++, macros, g++

There is such code:

```
#include <assert.h>

void fun1()
{
   int x;
}

int main()
{
   assert(true
         ==true);
   return 0;
}

void fun2()
{
   int y;
}
```

There are two unused variables `x` and `y` which should be reported by a compiler when option `-Wall` is passed.

Let's first run only preprocessor:

```
g++ main.cpp -Wall -E -o main2.cpp
```

The output:

```
a lot of stuff from assert.h
...
# 2 "main.cpp" 2

void fun1()
{
   int x;
}

int main()
{
   ((true ==true) ? static_cast<void> (0) : __assert_fail ("true ==true",
 "main.cpp"
# 10 "main.cpp" 3 4
   ,
 11
# 10 "main.cpp" 3 4
   , __PRETTY_FUNCTION__))
                ;
   return 0;
}

void fun2()
{
   int y;
}
```

Let's try to compile this thing:

```
$ g++ main2.cpp -Wall -c -o main2.o
main.cpp: In function ‘void fun1()’:
main.cpp:5:8: warning: unused variable ‘x’ [-Wunused-variable]
    int x;
        ^
```

There is only a warning for the first unused variable but not for the second. It looks like that some warnings are disabled after the `assert` macro.

But when I change `assert` to be one-line statement:

```
int main()
{
   assert(true==true);
   return 0;
}
```

then these things:

```
# 10 "main.cpp" 3 4
```

are **not** generated and when I compile the preprocessed file then I get two warnings as expected for two unused variables.

I will get also two warnings when I remove `3 4` from these directives in preprocessed file:

```
# 10 "main.cpp" 3 4
```

to

```
# 10 "main.cpp"
```

Why the behaviour of the compiler (g++ 4.9.2) is so different when the condition inside `assert` is one-line and multiline?

Comment: Maybe related to [this 10 year old gcc issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29314038/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour This problem is not only about unitialised variables but also about other warnings like comparing signed and unsigned etc.