# How to force compiler to set a non-zero value to uninitialized variables?

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, compiler-options, value-initialization

I am playing with [C++ value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).
Therefore, I am printing uninitialized values in order to highlight (un)initialization depending on C++ standard version.
But uninitialized values convey often the zero value :-(

**How to highlight if a variable has not been initialized?**
(i.e., How to say to the compiler to use a specific value for uninitialized variables?)

Maybe this could be done using a *magic* user-provided allocator...

---

**EDIT:** My below snippets is not for production. I just wanted to check the implementation (by the compiler) of the C++ Standard about uninitialization/value-initialization/zero-initialization/default-initialization mechanisms. I do not want compiler warnings about uninitialized variables. I do not want to use MemoryCheckers. I just want to highlight that compiler zero-initializes some variables, default-initializes some other variables and does not initialize at all other variables. And this initialization behavior also depends on the version of C++ Standard. If you think the best way is to use compilers warnings or MemoryCheckers, please provide an answer using the below snippets.

---

<sub>Please do not read below detailed attempts if you have already understood my question.</sub>

---

You can [build/run my first snippet on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4aa1f830f59fa4cd)

```
#include <iostream>

struct A  {
  A() {} // user-defined default ctor does not initialize i
  int i;
};

struct B {
  A a;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << B().a.i << '\n';
    // Results: C++03 -> uninitialized
    //          C++11 -> zero-initialized

  std::cout << B{}.a.i << '\n';
    // Results: C++03 -> Do not compile - B{} is correct since C++11
    //          C++11 -> uninitialized because
    //          DR1301 defines B{} as an aggregate-initialization
}   //          => A is value-initialized using the user-defined ctor
```

When compiled using `-std=c++03` the execute may probably prints a zero value but I would prefer a non-zero value.

```
0
```

Possible output using `-std=c++11`

```
0
1208617840
```

Another possible output using `-std=c++11`

```
0
-201855824
```

But [my more advanced snippet](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17caede8dad15fa7) has now zero-values for uninitialized object `B{}.a.i` :-(

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  A() {} // user-defined ctor does not initialize i
  int i;
};

struct B  {
  A a;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout <<"-----------"<< __cplusplus <<"-----------" "\n";
  std::cout <<"B().a.i            = "<<         B().a.i <<'\n';
  std::cout <<"B{}.a.i            = "<<         B{}.a.i <<'\n';

  int d;
  d = 42;
  std::cout <<"(new(&d) B  )->a.i = "<< (new(&d) B  )->a.i <<'\n';
  d = 42;
  std::cout <<"(new(&d) B())->a.i = "<< (new(&d) B())->a.i <<'\n';
  d = 42;
  std::cout <<"(new(&d) B{})->a.i = "<< (new(&d) B{})->a.i <<'\n';
}
```

Build/Run output:

```
> g++ -std=c++03 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp && ./a.out
-----------199711-----------
B().a.i            = 0
(new(&d) B  )->a.i = 42
(new(&d) B())->a.i = 0

> g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp && ./a.out
-----------201103-----------
B().a.i            = 0
B{}.a.i            = 0
(new(&d) B  )->a.i = 42
(new(&d) B())->a.i = 0
(new(&d) B{})->a.i = 0

> g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp && ./a.out
-----------201402-----------
B().a.i            = 0
B{}.a.i            = 0
(new(&d) B  )->a.i = 42
(new(&d) B())->a.i = 0
(new(&d) B{})->a.i = 0
```

Comment: There's no way to distinguish an uninitialized variable during run-time.

Comment: Maybe you want something like Clang's [MemorySanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html)?

Comment: Some compilers have debug options for setting uninitialized memory to special values, but it depends on which compiler you're using.

Comment: Hi @DanHulme I can use g++ and clang++.

Comment: Compilers may use specific values for uninitialized values when building in debug mode. MSVC is known to do that to allow developpers to easily detect uninitialized memory when running a program through the debugger. But it is an implementation detail, and anyway, I really do not know how to control it, not how to do the same with other compilers.

Comment: Keep in mind that you're playing with a Heisenbug here. Since the reading of uninitialized variables is Undefined Behavior, and GCC is known to optimize based on an assumption of well-defined behavior including well-defined use of variables, the mere attempt to use _directly_ use an uninitialized variable may affect that variable, and others as well. In particular, GCC is known to outright remove code that touches uninitialized variables.

Comment: Does `g++ -Wuninitialized` not help you out?

Comment: Relevant for gcc [Why does GCC only sometimes detect the use of a variable before its initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29314038/1708801) note the quote for the gcc wiki: *Second, the set of false positives or negatives varies according to the optimisations enabled. This also causes high variability of the warnings reported when optimisations are added or modified between releases* which backs up MSalters comment.

Comment: @MarkB see my comment on `-Wuninitialized`

Comment: Hi @MarkB I do not want the compiler warns about uninitialized variables. I just want to highlight that compiler zero-initializes some variables, default-initializes some other variables and does not initialize at all the rest (this can also depend on the version of C++ Standard).

Comment: "I do not want the compiler warns about uninitialized variables". Why? This is exactly the thing you should be using, all the time. "I do not want to do the sane thing I want to solve my problem some other way". First do the sane thing, then see if you still have a problem.

Comment: Hi @Ben. Yes this snippet is not for production. It is just to check the implementation by the compiler of the C++ Standard about value-initialization / default-initialization / uninitialization mechanisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `clang++` instead of `g++`.

**`clang++` v3.7 has highlighted uninitialized values in my specific case.**

**Note:** This answer is based on C++ [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) that has changed since C++11. Value initialization is when parentheses/braces are empty: `T(); T{}; new T(); new T{};`

Build/Run below snippet on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6972398eb18d46f)

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  A() {} // ctor does not initialize 'i'
  int i;
};

struct B // implicit ctor
{
  A a;
  int i;
  void set() { a.i = i = 42; }
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const B& b)
{  os <<'\t'<< b.a.i <<'\t'<< b.i;  return os; }

int main()
{
  std::cout <<"----------"<< __cplusplus <<"----------" "\n";

  B b; // used to reset memory for 'placement new'

  b.set(); std::cout <<"new(&b)B   "<< *new(&b)B   <<'\n'; // All uninitialized (in all C++ standards)

  std::cout          <<"       B() "<< B()         <<'\n'; // B::A::i uninitialized in C++03, zero-initialized in C++11
  b.set(); std::cout <<"new(&b)B() "<< *new(&b)B() <<'\n'; // B::i zero-initialized (in all C++ standards)

#if __cplusplus > 2011*100                                 // B{} is aggregate-initialization (DR1301)
  std::cout          <<"       B{} "<< B{}         <<'\n'; // => B::A::i value-initialized
  b.set(); std::cout <<"new(&b)B{} "<< *new(&b)B{} <<'\n'; // => B::i     zero-initialized
#endif
}
```

**Build output & Possible run output**

```
> clang++ --version
clang version 3.7.0 (tags/RELEASE_370/final 246979)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

> clang++ -std=c++03 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp && ./a.out
----------199711----------
new(&b)B    42      42
       B()  0       0
new(&b)B()  0       0

> clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp && ./a.out
----------201103----------
new(&b)B    42      42
       B()  0       0
new(&b)B()  0       0
       B{}  4196348 0
new(&b)B{}  42      0

> clang++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp && ./a.out
----------201402----------
new(&b)B    42      42
       B()  0       0
new(&b)B()  0       0
       B{}  4196348 0
new(&b)B{}  42      0

> clang++ -std=c++1z -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp && ./a.out    
----------201406----------
new(&b)B    42      42
       B()  0       0
new(&b)B()  0       0
       B{}  4196348 0
new(&b)B{}  42      0
```