# g++ dangling pointer warning inconsistency?

Tags: c++, pointers, g++, compiler-warnings

Is this the same thing?

1.

```
int* f() {
    int x = 5;
    return &x;
}
```

2.

```
int* f() {
    int x = 5;
    int* pX = &x;
    return pX;
}
```

g++ only returns a warning for 1., why not 2.?

Comment: They are slightly different, in the first example `x` will be destroyed on function return. In the second one, address of `x `is already stored in `pX`, so destruction of `x` does not delete the value stored in `pX`, which you can return like a simple integer value.

Comment: @Alparslan: So pX keeps x on the stack?

Comment: No, it doesn't force X to be kept on stack, but it simple keeps the old address of X as a separate integer and you can return that even after X is destroyed.

Comment: @Alparslan: so 2. still has the same memory implications as 1.? That is, there is the possibility of 2. pointer to an inconsistent value?

Comment: Exactly, in both cases, the returned memory address will be invalid. And you can crash your program if you try to write on the returned address in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this the same thing?

Yes.

> g++ only returns a warning for 1., why not 2.?

I don't know for sure but my guess is that the `return` statement is one step removed from taking the address of a local variable. The compiler doesn't necessarily know how `pX` was set by the time the `return` statement is executed.

```
int* f() {
    int x = 5;

    // There is no problem here.
    int* pX = &x;

    // The compiler doesn't care to find out how pX was set.
    // it could have been pX = malloc(sizeof(int))
    // It assumes that pX is a valid pointer to return.
    return pX;
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu: I don't really understand your answer.

Comment: @wulfgar.pro, I added a bit more to the answer.

Comment: I see, so the same implications of 1. still exist for 2., it's just g++ doesn't catch such a scenario?

Answer (score 3):

I can get gcc to warn on both by turning on optimization [see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vbQuzOCmgeKDWdH2):

```
warning: address of local variable 'x' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
 int x = 5;
     ^

 warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
 return pX;
        ^
```

These types of warnings can often be effected by the optimization level, [gcc has a ten year old bug report on the inconsistency of the detecting use of a variable before initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29314038/1708801) which varies greatly based on optimization level.

At the end of the day when you have undefined behavior the compiler is not obligated to provide a diagnostic and in fact many of the behaviors are designated as undefined as opposed to ill-formed because of the [difficulty of consistently detecting them](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/99711/84604).