# gcc -Wall -Wuninitialized is not throwing warning for uninitialized variable

Tags: c, gcc

gcc version - gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4

Compiling below code with -Wall -Wuninitialized is throwing warning as expected
warning: ‘test’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void check (int test )
{
   printf("%d",test);
}

int
main()
{
   int test;
   check(test);
   return 0;
}
```

But compiling below code with -Wall -Wuninitialized is not throwing warning

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void check (int test )
{
   printf("%d",test);
}

int
main()
{
   int test;
   int condition = 0;

   if(condition == 27)
      test = 10;

   check(test);
   return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't it throw warning?. is it anyway related to compiler optimization?

Comment: There is no requirement by the standard a compiler has to warn about this type of undefined behaviour.

Comment: test = 10; I guess it takes the variable as used, even if there's a path unitialized.

Comment: [Related thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705880/gcc-failing-to-warn-of-uninitialized-variable?rq=1)

Comment: According to [here](http://goo.gl/jhufUK), gcc does warn about this since version 4.9 .  You could upgrade your compiler version perhaps.

Comment: @M.M I have 4.9.3 and 5.3.0 no warning even with all those flags.

Comment: @Schwern there is a dropdown box where you select the compiler version. I linked to version 4.9.0 but you can change it.  Versions 4.9.0, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 5.3.0, and 6, all give the warning. Version 4.9.2 does not.  (I didn't try varying the `-O` flag)

Comment: @M.M Yeah, I see that. I can't replicate it. *shrug*

Answer (score 2):

> What an user understands as a false positive may be different for the particular
>   user. Some users are interested in cases that are hidden because of
>   actions of the optimizers combined with the current environment.
>   However, many users aren't, since that case is hidden because it
>   cannot arise in the compiled code. The canonical example is (MM05):
>
> ```
> int x;
> if (f ())
> x = 3;
> return x;
> ```
>
> where 'f' always return non-zero for the current environment, and
>   thus, it may be optimised away. Here, a group of users would like to
>   get an uninitialized warning since 'f' may return zero when compiled
>   elsewhere. Yet, other group of users would consider spurious a warning
>   about a situation that cannot arise in the executable being compiled.

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Better_Uninitialized_Warnings#Proposal

---

EDIT: MMO5 is already fixed

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Better_Uninitialized_Warnings#MM05

Answer (score 1):

Yes, gcc is not warning you because the code is optimized away.  Some people think this is the right thing, because it might be that way by a compile time configuration value.  Others think it's the wrong thing, because it hides possible mistakes.

You are not the first to notice this problem with GCC.  [There's a whole proposal about it](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Better_Uninitialized_Warnings#Rationale).

clang with `-Wall` detects the problem and even suggests a fix.

```
$ make
cc -Wall -g    test.c   -o test
test.c:15:7: warning: variable 'test' is used uninitialized whenever 'if' condition is false
      [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
   if(condition == 27)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:18:10: note: uninitialized use occurs here
   check(test);
         ^~~~
test.c:15:4: note: remove the 'if' if its condition is always true
   if(condition == 27)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:12:12: note: initialize the variable 'test' to silence this warning
   int test;
           ^
            = 0
1 warning generated.
```