# C program doesn't print first line (row) but prints all the others

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to print an inverted pyramid(or triangle) with `*`, but when I run the following code it *skips* the `for` loop for `i=rows`, i.e. doesn't print any `*`,
the second iteration goes *smoothly*. I assume the problem is within `while` loop but I just don't see it clearly.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int k, i, space, rows;

    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("\n");

    for (i = rows; i >= 1; i--, k = 0) {
        for (space = 1; space <= rows - i; space++) {
            printf("  ");
        }
        printf("smth");
        while (k < 2 * i - 1) {
            printf("* ");
            k++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `k` is uninitialised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program doesn't work as you expect because you have *undefined behavior* in the code, since you use the uninitialized variable `k` before it is initialized.

Uninitialized variables have an *indeterminate* value, and using them (except to initialize the variable) is undefined behavior.

You should initialize `k` before you use it, not only at the end of the outer loop. Something like

```
for(i=rows,k=0; i>=1; i--,k=0)
//        ^^^^
// Added initial initialization
```

***Or*** since you don't use `k` except in the `while` loop, why not turn it into a `for` loop? Like

```
for (int k = 0; k < 2 * i - 1; ++k)
    printf("* ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You only initialize `k` in the increment part of the `for` loop... Hence `k` is uninitialized for the first iteration.  It happens to have a `0` or negative value, but its initial value is actually indeterminate: the program invokes undefined behavior.

If you compile with `gcc -Wall -W -O2` or `clang -Weverything -O2`, the compiler will warn you about this.

You should always use standard idioms, it helps avoid such mistakes.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int k, i, space, rows;

    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &rows) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("\n");

    for (i = rows; i > 0; i--) {
        for (space = 0; space < rows - i; space++) {
            printf("  ");
        }
        printf("smth");
        for (k = 0; k < 2 * i - 1; k++) {
            printf("* ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks strange but `gcc` don't emmit a warning even with `Wall` or `Wuninitialized` flags on

Comment: @AlterMann: Strange indeed... I use `clang` and get the warning with `-Weverything`.  Try `-Wall -W`.

Comment: Yep!! related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705880/gcc-failing-to-warn-of-uninitialized-variable

Comment: mmm, it works when used with some optimization: `-O2`, really strange

Comment: @AlterMann: I guess the uninitialized variable analysis is performed as a side effect of life time analysis and register allocation performed only with `-O2` and above.